# node.js - blessed textarea give repeat text

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, command-line-interface, blessed

i am trying to make a chatroom app with blessed, here is my code:
**index.js**

```js
const blessed = require('blessed')
const EventEmitter = require('events')

// Create a eventemitter
var chatroom = new EventEmitter()

// Create a screen object.
var screen = blessed.screen({smartCSR: true, dockBorders: true})
screen.title = 'chatroom'
screen.key(['C-c', 'escape'], () => { // exit
    return process.exit(0)
})

var chatarea = blessed.box({
    parent: screen,
    top: 0,
    title: 'chatroom',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%-2',
    tags: true,
    border: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    style: {
        fg: 'white',
    }
})

var form = blessed.form({
    parent: screen,
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: 3,
    keys: true,
    border: {
        type: 'line'
    }
})

var input = blessed.textarea({
    parent: screen,
    bottom: 1,
    left: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: 1,
    input: true,
    focused: true,
    inputOnFocus: true,
    tags: true,
    
});
input.focus()

screen.append(chatarea)
screen.append(form)
screen.append(input)
screen.render()
```

but it always repeat all the key i am typing, for example: if i type 'hello', it will show hheelllloo like this:
[image: img1]

it will repeat all the chars, how can i fix this? thx

Answer (score 0):

You can just move `input.focus()` after `screen.render()`